# Python: Setting the metaclass for all files in a folder

Tags: python, package, project, environment-variables, metaclass

I wrote a metaclass that I'm using for logging purposes in my python project. It makes every class automatically log all activity. The only issue is that I don't want to go into every file and have to add in:

```
__metaclass__ = myMeta
```

Is there a way to set the metaclass in the top level folder so that all the files underneath use that metaclass?

Comment: @slashdottir: there you go, answer updated to cover 2.7. It's yet another hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can only specify the metaclass per class or per module. You cannot set it for the whole package.

In Python 3.1 and onwards, you *can* intercept the `builtins.__build_class__` hook and insert a metaclass programatically, see [Overriding the default type() metaclass before Python runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293172/overriding-the-default-type-metaclass-before-python-runs/15392133#15392133).

In Python 2.7, you could replace `__builtins__.object` with a subclass that uses your metaclass. Like the `builtins.__build_class__` hook, this is *advanced hackery* and break your code as much as getting your metaclass in everwhere.

Do so by replacing the `object` reference on the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html):

```
import __builtin__


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, *args):
        # do something in the metaclass
        return super(MetaClass, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, *args)


orig_object = __builtin__.orig_object


class metaobject(orig_object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass


def enable():
    # *replace* object with one that uses your metaclass
    __builtin__.object = metaobject

def disable():
    __builtin__.object = orig_object
```

Run `enable()` this before importing your package and all new-style classes (those that *can* support a metaclass) will have your metaclass. Note that this behaviour now will propagate to **all** Python code not already loaded, including the standard library, as your package imports code. You probably want to use:

```
enable()
import package
disable()
```

to limit the effects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple technique. Just *subclass* the *class* itself with `__metaclass__` attribute in the subclass. This process can be automated.

util.py

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.second)
```

main.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from util import A

def meta(*args):
    cls = type(*args)
    setattr(cls, 'created', datetime.now().ctime())
    return cls

try:
    print(A.created)
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)

class A(A):
    __metaclass__ = meta

print(A.created, str(A('Michael', 'Jackson')))
```

Test;

```
$ python main.py 
type object 'A' has no attribute 'created'
('Wed Mar  9 22:58:16 2016', 'Michael Jackson')
```